# Jenkins: C:Program No such file or directory

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins script in the cache gives the following error

> C:\Users\svcBICM\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins6041485005934862737.sh:
>   line 16: C:\Program: No such file or directory

I am running the above in Windows. The previous node path was is `c:\root\nodejs` which was working and the current path is in `c:\Program Files\` .

So I am getting the following error since maybe the jenkins is taking `c:\Program` as one string and `Files\` as another one. Is there any way to fix this? The above jenkins script is not created by me , but you can say its auto-generated and not available to view when i go to the location.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using  double quotes. `"Program Files"` I faced similar problem and resolved using double quotes

Comment: can replace \ with \\

Answer (score 0):

As Rohit already said, you can fix the issue just by using double quotes:  `"c:\Program Files\"`.